# Is it possible to create a Java annotation with an attribute that can be any annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, return-type

I know that the following is possible, and I've done it many times before:

```
public @interface Foo { }

public @interface Bar
{
    Foo[] foos() default {};
}

...

@Bar(foos={@Foo, @Foo})
void doSomething();
```

However, I want to have an annotation attribute whose return type is *any* annotation, not just foo. For example:

```
public @interface Foo1 { }

public @interface Foo2 { }

public @interface Bar
{
    Annotation[] annotations() default {};
}

...

@Bar(annotations={@Foo1, @Foo2})
void doSomething();
```

Is this possible? I'm not finding a way to do it, but I'm hoping that I'm overlooking something. The [Java language guide for annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html) says:

> Return types are restricted to primitives, String, Class, enums, annotations, and arrays of the preceding types.

What I want to do is clearly create an attribute with a return type of annotation, so in theory it should be possible, but it's not looking good.

Comment: Why would you want something like that?

Comment: Have you tried it already?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, so that I can do this with JSR-303/349 Bean Validation: `@Constraint(validatedBy=ConditionalValidator.class) public @interface Conditional { String conditionField(); Annotation conditionConstraint(); String targetField(); Annotation[] targetConstraints(); ... }`, where the target constraints are validated on field A assuming that the conditional constraint on field B passes: `@Conditional(conditionField="fieldB", conditionConstraint=@AssertTrue, targetField="fieldA", targetConstraints={@NotBlank(...)}) public class MyBean { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. Annotation isn't an annotation, it's a class. You can't return classes, other than String and Class.

Comment: Actually, it's an interface, but you hit the nail on the head here! +1

Comment: So maybe using `Annotation[]` isn't possible, but is there some other way to specify _any_ annotation? What I want to do here seems to be supported per the guide, it's just not clear how to do it, if it's even possible. I'm not demanding that I be allowed to return `Annotation` necessarily. Just a generic annotation as opposed to a specific annotation (which is clearly possible per the first example).